# Populating a ListBox (WPF) with an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, listbox

I've perused all the related questions on this site, but for some reason I'm not able to populate my two `ListBox`es with two `ObservableCollection`s. Is the issue with my binding or somewhere in the model?

**Model:**

```
public class DataModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<object> List1
    {
        get
        {
            return this.List1;
        }
        set
        {
            this.List1 = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("List1");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<object> List2
    {
        get
        {
            return this.List2;
        }
        set
        {
            this.List2 = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("List2");
        }
    }

    public DataModel(ObservableCollection<object> _list1, ObservableCollection<object> _list2)
    {
        this.List1 = _list1;
        this.List2 = _list2;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML.cs:**

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<object> l;
    public ObservableCollection<object> m;

    public UserControl1()
    {
        l = new ObservableCollection<object> { "test1a", "test1b" };
        m = new ObservableCollection<object> { "test2a", "test2b" };
        InitializeComponent();
        DataModel inst = new DataModel(l, m);
        this.DataContext = inst;
        this.TelProps.ItemsSource = l;
        this.SurProps.ItemsSource = m;
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Grid Name="Grid" DataContext="inst">
    <ListBox Name="FirstProps" 
             DataContext="{Binding Source=inst}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding List1}"
             DisplayMemberPath="List1" />
    <ListBox Name="SecondProps" 
             DataContext="{Binding Source=inst}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding List2}"
             DisplayMemberPath="List2" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Something doesen't look right with your code. You will get StackOverflowException when trying to either get or set the value of properties List1 or List2. You need backing fields there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `DisplayMemberPath` specifier.  This is saying to look for the `List1` property  *on each item* of `List1`.  Since `List1` merely contains a set of strings, there is no `List1` property on `System.String`, so you get a binding error.